# Conditional Probability on Cards

Tags: probability, statistics

Two cards were dealt from a deck of $8$ cards: four red cards labelled $A$, $B$, $C$, $D$ and
four green cards also labelled $A$, $B$, $C$, $D$. A winning pair is two cards of the same
color or two of the same letter. What is the probability of getting a winning pair?

I have already done the following:

Let $\alpha$ be the event that you get two cards of the same color and
$\beta$ is the event you get two cards of the same letter.

with $P(\alpha) = 1/2$ and $P(\beta) = 1/4$

I then went on to do $P(\alpha | \beta)$,  I need help carrying on.

Comment: Are the cards replaced after being handed out? If not then you are wrong with $P(\alpha)=\frac12$. And why finding $P(\alpha\mid \beta)$. Isn't it $P(\alpha\cup \beta)$ that you are after?

Answer (score 2):

Let the first card be handed out. Then $3+1=4$ cards of the $7$ cards that are left will take care of a winning pair. So what would be the probability?

Comment: My answer too. Always important to recognize when the result of the first event matters versus when it doesn't matter!

Answer (score 1):

I am assuming that cards aren't replaced after choosing them. If that's not the case, please let me know.

Look at it using the classical definition of probability.

What are the total number of cases favouring you: 4 (same letter) + 4C2 (two reds) + 4C2 (two greens).

What are the total number of cases: 8C2 (choosing any two cards from the 8 given cards).

Your answer: Favourable cases / Total Cases = (4 + 6 + 6) / (28) = 4/7

PS: The P(A) you have written in the question which corresponds to the probability of picking two cards of the same colour is not 1/2. It is actually 3/7. You can either interpret it as (4C2 + 4C2) / (8C2), or you can say that after picking up a card of any colour, you have 3 options to pick a card of the same colour, and 4 to pick a card of the other colour, which makes it 3 / (3+4) which is equal to 3/7

Comment: Now let's hope on non-replacement ;).